# Automatically delete .aux file following an error

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files

How can I have LaTeX automatically delete the .aux file following an error I made? I may have missed a `}` for example.

Any error I make stops the compile. After I fix the error and re-run, LaTeX fails to compile and warns me about a corrupt `.aux` file. Then I need to delete the old `.aux` file and run LaTeX a third time. To get all of the references correct, I need to run it a fourth time.  All for one missing `}`.

I am working on a huge document so this takes a while to perform.  Also, I am running Windows so (please!) no solutions in Linux.

Comment: I seldom get a corrupted aux after an error. How do you stop latex when you get an error? Do you kill the application?

Comment: Maybe the first step is to speed up compilation. E.g. writing `draft` into the global options, comment out hyperref, use lmodern as font. Especially the hyperref package may lead to error messages about the aux-file and require a second run.

Answer (score 1):

You can install LaTeXmk (can be done on Windows (http://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html).

Then go into your editors settings, there you should find a compile command somewhere.

Change this command to `latexmk -pdf -c`
This should run all Texfiles in the directory. If your editor has a way of specifying which file to come pile, change the command to `latexmk -pdf -c your-editors-way-of-specifying-file`.

The `-pdf` ensures that you get a pdf and the `-c` deletes all the generated files.