# how i can automatically delete .aux? SOLVED

Tags: auxiliary-files, compilation-error

Please, is there any way to configure this? .
Before this error did not happen, however it is solved if I manually delete the .aux file.[this is a similar error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399887/automatically-delete-aux-file-following-an-error).

```
(./documento1.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.79 \@wr

?
```

SOLVED:
[The same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66015/errors-in-tables-then-runaway-argument-at-begindocument)

Comment: You don't want to delete the aux-file, you need it. So better correct your code so that it doesn't write a broken aux-file.

Comment: After one successful latex pass (without any errors in the aux file), the aux file will be clean.

Comment: But, if i delete the file .aux ...this problem solve @Fischer...why?

Comment: The aux is how citations and references work, so you needed. We see this issue with macros that does not finish writing their stuff to the aux or programmes that kills the latex process before latex has finished writing to the aux. This leaves the aux in an undefined state and removing it often solves the issue. But auto removing after each processing is a bad idea as you need up having to compile at  least twice in order for all the references to be up to date.

Comment: @daleif Great;;Thanks for the explanation, I was curious. so is normal this error?

Comment: I wouldn't call it normal, but it's seen from time to time. The whole trick is looking at your error message and realising that it comes from the aux (line 1), and since latex generates the aux it is safe deleting it if there is an error. After deleting it you can compile again to see if it works. If it does, some fluke occurred. Error appears again, then something is wrong with your doc

Comment: @daleif yes, i was doing that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your compile in a bash script that starts with

```
rm *.aux
```

or

```
 rm $1.aux
```

and then does as many  compiles as necessary to get the cross references in the aux file into the typeset document.